# Reporting Services not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services

I have DC 1, SQL1 and SP1 in a 3 tier virtual environment.

In SP1 I installed Reporting Services - SharePoint Integrated and Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint. Once the install was done I tried to create the service application but the option wasn't available.

So I thought, maybe SSRS had to be installed on the same sever that the engine is running on (SQL1) so that's what I did and that didn't fix anything. I went into the Configuration Manager but I don't see a Reporting Services instance. The Reporting Configuration Wizard gives me an error saying it can't find the Reporting Server.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Need more info. What version of SharePoint (2010, 2013) and what version of SSRS (2008 R2, 2012, 2014)? SP 2013 requires SSRS 2012 SP1 or higher, and SSRS must always be installed on a SharePoint server in the farm. You also need to, for 2012+, run Install-SPRSService and Install-SPRSServiceProxy before you can create the Service Application.

Comment: Hi, I got it working after running the powershell commands. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to answer. Run Install-SPRSService and Install-SPRSServiceProxy. Create the SA after that.